# Column filtering in jQuery datatables in jQuery way

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable which has only checkboxs in one column. How to implement a filter (drop down with `checked` and `uncheked` options) on that column which should filter and display rows with `checked`/`unchecked` checkboxes on select of drop down?

Answer (score 0):

Here is exactly what you want.Look at a working [Jsfiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/2042/)

You can use :

```
$('#rowclick2 tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {        
        $tr = $(this);
        $('td', $tr).each(function() {
            // If you need the TD's
        });
        ....     

    });
```

Comment: Well..!! That was good. But what if there are more rows, which are in different pages(Pagination). I would like to know the implementation specific to 'Jquery datatable'.

Comment: I mean showing selected/unselected ones from a table with pagination.